# Routing HTTP/HTTPS traffic from one Linux server to another Linux server

Tags: routing, web-server, openvpn, reverse-proxy, forwarding

The DNS for the domain.com is pointing at Server1 (it has a public ip address).

The webserver is running on Server 2 (no public IP address, but connected to Server1 via OVPN).

Is it possible to route the incoming traffic for ports 80 and 443 from Server1 to Server2?

Comment: take a look at haproxy

Comment: Yes with iptables/nftables dnat /snat or ip rule dport selector or nginx reverse proxy

Answer (score 0):

Run a reverse proxy on server1.example.net, sending requests for the relevant domains onto server2.example.net.

Name based virtual hosts may a good idea. In other words, the domain users are requesting is actually [www.example.com](http://www.example.com). If so, you want to match on Host header.

A load balancer can do this, even if there might only be server2 as a single backend. haproxy is just one implementation you might choose, there are many others.